# Processing stacks of parameters using 'for-each' in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, param

I have a series of param elements inside a template that rely upon each other (i.e. each subsequent param uses the value of the previous one as part of it's XPath)

e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="input1" select="path/node/@value"/>

<xsl:param name="input2" select="path/anothernode[@value=$input1]/anothervalue"/>

<xsl:param name="input3" select="path/thirdnode[@value=$input2]/@endvalue"/>
```

etc. etc.

The stack of params works perfectly on a single run through. However, when I use a for-each loop to call the template and pass the for-each value to it using xsl:with-param, only the top param is processed - the value is NOT passed to the next the parameter.

Here's my full xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/" name="test">

  <xsl:param name="memberId"    
    select="PLMXML/Organisation/UserData/UserValue/UserList/Item/@value"/>
  <xsl:param name="memberRef" 
    select="PLMXML/OrganisationMember[@id=$memberId]/@memberRef"/>  
  <xsl:param name="memberRef2"    
    select="translate($memberRef,'#','')"/> 
  <xsl:param name="userId"    
    select="PLMXML/User[@id=$memberRef2]/@personRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="userId2"    
    select="translate($userId,'#','')"/>    
  <xsl:param name="personName"    
    select="PLMXML/Person[@id=$userId2]/@lastName"/>
  <xsl:param name="groupRef"    
    select="PLMXML/User[@id=$memberRef2]/UserData/UserValue/@dataRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="groupRef2"    
    select="translate($groupRef,'#','')"/>
  <xsl:param name="groupName"    
    select="PLMXML/Organisation[@id=$groupRef2]/@name"/>
  <xsl:param name="roleRef"    
    select="PLMXML/Organisation[@id=$groupRef2]/UserData/UserValue/@dataRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="roleRef2"    
    select="translate($roleRef,'#','')"/>
  <xsl:param name="roleName"    
    select="PLMXML/Role[@id=$roleRef2]/@name"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$memberId"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$memberRef"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$personName"/>  
  <xsl:value-of select="$groupName"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$roleName"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="PLMXML/Organisation/UserData/UserValue/UserList/Item/@value">

    <xsl:call-template name="test">

      <xsl:with-param name="memberId" select="."/>

    </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the for-each loop only populates the top variable of the stack in template 'test' - i.e. `xsl:value-of select="$memberId"/>` works but `<xsl:value-of select="$memberRef"/>` does not.

Any ideas on how to work around this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: "when I use a for-each loop" - where is the loop code?

Comment: I'll have to ask a new question since the code is far too long for this comment box.

Comment: We can't debug your code without seeing it. If the code is too long to post, cut it down to something simpler that still demonstrates the problem: often the exercise of doing this helps you locate the bug.

Comment: You should edit this question with your code and close the new question that you created (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786219/using-multiple-paramenters-in-a-template-called-by-for-each).

Comment: That code is a mess. I don't even know what you are trying to achieve with that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is one of context; where you are currently positioned in the XML. Consider your **xsl:for-each** loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="PLMXML/Organisation/UserData/UserValue/UserList/Item/@value">
```

You are looping over **@value** attributes, meaning within the loop you are positioned on a **@value** attribute, and consequently any relative xpath expressions will be relative to that. When you do your **xsl:call-template** you will still be positioned on the **@value** attribute, and so all the xpath expressions in the **xsl:param** statements will be relative to that.

```
<xsl:param name="memberRef" 
     select="PLMXML/OrganisationMember[@id=$memberId]/@memberRef"/>
```

That is to say, the **select** statement is looking for a **PLMXML** element underneath the current **@value**, which clearly does not exist!

The reason the first parameter, **memberId**, works is because you pass an explicit value to that, and so that will be used instead of the default value in the **select** attribute. All the other parameters will not work because they will use the default value.

The solution is, probably, is to make all your parameters have absolute expressions, which means prefixing them with a `/`.

```
<xsl:param name="memberRef" 
     select="/PLMXML/OrganisationMember[@id=$memberId]/@memberRef"/>
```

The `/` represents the top level document node, and so the xpath expression will then be relative to that, and not the current node.

Note, you might consider using **xsl:key** in this instance to look-up such elements. For example

```
<xsl:key name="OrganisationMember" match="OrganisationMember" use="@id" />
```

Then the param statement becomes this:

```
<xsl:param name="memberRef" select="key('OrganisationMember', $memberId)/@memberRef"/>
```

As an aside, it is considered an error to have two templates of equal priority matching the same thing. So, your first 'named' template should probably have the **match** attribute removed. i.e. Instead of `<xsl:template match="/" name="test">`, do this

```
 <xsl:template name="test">
```