# Using multiple paramenters in a template called by for-each?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

Here's my full xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/" name="test">

  <xsl:param name="memberId"    
    select="PLMXML/Organisation/UserData/UserValue/UserList/Item/@value"/>
  <xsl:param name="memberRef" 
    select="PLMXML/OrganisationMember[@id=$memberId]/@memberRef"/>  
  <xsl:param name="memberRef2"    
    select="translate($memberRef,'#','')"/> 
  <xsl:param name="userId"    
    select="PLMXML/User[@id=$memberRef2]/@personRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="userId2"    
    select="translate($userId,'#','')"/>    
  <xsl:param name="personName"    
    select="PLMXML/Person[@id=$userId2]/@lastName"/>
  <xsl:param name="groupRef"    
    select="PLMXML/User[@id=$memberRef2]/UserData/UserValue/@dataRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="groupRef2"    
    select="translate($groupRef,'#','')"/>
  <xsl:param name="groupName"    
    select="PLMXML/Organisation[@id=$groupRef2]/@name"/>
  <xsl:param name="roleRef"    
    select="PLMXML/Organisation[@id=$groupRef2]/UserData/UserValue/@dataRef"/>
  <xsl:param name="roleRef2"    
    select="translate($roleRef,'#','')"/>
  <xsl:param name="roleName"    
    select="PLMXML/Role[@id=$roleRef2]/@name"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$memberId"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$memberRef"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$personName"/>  
  <xsl:value-of select="$groupName"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$roleName"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="PLMXML/Organisation/UserData/UserValue/UserList/Item/@value">

    <xsl:call-template name="test">

      <xsl:with-param name="memberId" select="."/>

    </xsl:call-template>

  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the for-each loop only populates the top variable of the stack in template 'test' - i.e. `xsl:value-of select="$memberId"/>` works but `<xsl:value-of select="$memberRef"/>` does not.

Any ideas on how to work around this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Typo in the paragraph above: "xsl:value-of $memberId work but xsl:value-of $memberRef does not"

Comment: You should edit your original question instead of creating a new one.